# Resize a locked form programmatically?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form acting as a sidebar, that will always be locked in position, and width. However, if I were to resize the MDI Container, this form should also grow to fit the Parent form length-ways.

For example, if I were to use a method in the Parent form like so:

```
private void ParentForm_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormWindowState LastWindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;

    if (this.WindowState != LastWindowState)
    {
        if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized)
            ResizeChildForm(this);
    }
}
```

And then in the Child form, if I have the property `Locked = true;` will I have to disable that, resize the form, then enable that again? I.e.

```
private void ResizeChildForm(ParentForm)
{
    this.Locked = false;
    //resize form
    this.Locked = true;
}
```

Or can I just change the size of the form without having to change that property?

Comment: It is a design-time only property, you can't use it in code.  Should be obvious from the compile errors you get.  So no, there's nothing you have to "disable".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question,

> can I just change the size of the form without having to change that property?

Yes you can, see this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984384(v=vs.71).aspx) for more details.

**Note from the article** :

> Locking controls prevents them from being dragged to a new size or location on the design surface. However, you can still change the size or location of controls by means of the Properties window or in code.